# How to save and load a structure of interfaces in go

Tags: go, encoding, interface, decoding

Coming from python I am used to be able to write a class with custom methods. Initiate it, save the object and load this again. I am trying to accomplish something similar in go. After reading about serialization I tried to use the marshall/unmarshall approach.

But below code deos not work as it results in method.Method = nil. I want to be able to call method.Method.Calculcate()

Below is my attempt.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Calculator struct {
    Method Method `json:"Method"`
}

type method1 struct {
    Input string `json:"input"`
}

func NewMethod1(input string) Method {
    return &method1{
        Input: input,
    }
}

type method2 struct {
    Input string `json:"input"`
}

func NewMethod2(input string) Method {
    return &method2{
        Input: input,
    }
}

type Method interface {
    Calculcate()
}

func (m *method1) Calculcate() {
}
func (m *method2) Calculcate() {
    }

func main() {
    model := Calculator{
        Method: NewMethod1("inputData"),
    }
    model.Method.Calculcate()
    var jsonData []byte
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(model)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(jsonData))

    var method Calculator
    json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &method)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

I want to load the struct and use the same code to initiate method1 as method 2 when calculcating. This means I don't know in advance whether I am loading method 1 or method 2. Below is a little bit of pseudocode explaining what I want.

```
Calculator :=Load Calculator()
model := Calculator{
    Method: NewMethod1("inputData"),
}
model.Method.Calculcate()
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're expecting your example code to do or what about it that's not working. Additionally the whole point of the question seems to be about serialization and your psuedo code doesn't use any. Please clarify. *I tried to use the marshall/unmarshall approach, but this does doesn't seem to work for my usecase as it leaves the interfaces = nil.* Maybe show the code that you tried to get this result and it would be a lot easier to explain what you are doing wrong if anything.

Comment: @super The asker included his code which demonstrates it properly.

Comment: @icza Demonstrates what? The code prints the values that he assigned to them after it being converted to JSON. So... if you have some telepathic knowledge about the question please go ahead and clarify.

Comment: The problem is that decoding a JSON does not know what concrete type to use when a field type is interface. It _might_ be obvious in your example, but just think a little further: you send this JSON over to another computer trying to decode it. The other computer might have a different version of the same type or it might not even have it.

Comment: After unmarschalling, method.Calculator = nil. I obviously want it to have  to be equal to NewMethod1.

Comment: The `encoding/json` package rightfully refuses to decode into the field `Calculator.Method` because it doesn't know how to. You may use the `encoding/gob` package if you want to encocde / decode interface values.

Comment: @MathiasRa No. It's not obvious. Hence my comment. Leaving something out of the question and realying on other people to assume the right thing is not really an approach suited for this kind of question/answer board.

Comment: @super I assume you didn't read the last bit where I wrote what I wanted. This would obviously not be possible if the value is nil.

Comment: @MathiasRa I did. Your psuedo code initialized a `Calculator` from a call to `NewMethod1`, passing in a string literal. How is that desciptive of what you want to achieve? It literally has nothing to do with marshalling or serialization.

Comment: @MathiasRa Look, either you accept my feedback and try to improve your question, or you don't. No need to argue about it. I think the fact that you have 0 upvotes on your question and 0 upvotes on the answer speaks a lot for itself. The question is most likely not going to be useful to anyone except you as it stands. Which might not mean anything to you, but that's the goal of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that decoding a JSON does not know what concrete type to use when a field has an interface type (multiple types may implement an interface). It might be obvious in your example, but just think a little further: you send this JSON over to another computer trying to decode it. **The JSON representation does not record the concrete type for interface values** (which in this case is `*main.method1`), so the other end does not know what to instantiate for the interface field `Calculator.Method`.

If you need this kind of serialization and deserialization, use the [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) package instead. That package also writes type information so the decoder part *at least knows the type name*. `encoding/gob` does not transmit type definition, so if the other part has a different version of the type, the process can also fail. This is documented in the package doc:

> Interface types are not checked for compatibility; all interface types are treated, for transmission, as members of a single "interface" type, analogous to int or []byte - in effect they're all treated as interface{}. Interface values are transmitted as a string identifying the concrete type being sent (a name that must be pre-defined by calling Register), followed by a byte count of the length of the following data (so the value can be skipped if it cannot be stored), followed by the usual encoding of concrete (dynamic) value stored in the interface value. (A nil interface value is identified by the empty string and transmits no value.) Upon receipt, the decoder verifies that the unpacked concrete item satisfies the interface of the receiving variable.

Also for the `encoding/gob` package to be able to instantiate a type based on its name, you have to register these types, more specifically values of these types.

This is a working example using `encoding/gob`:

First let's improve the `Calculate()` methods to see that they are called:

```
func (m *method1) Calculcate() {
    fmt.Println("method1.Calculate() called, input:", m.Input)
}

func (m *method2) Calculcate() {
    fmt.Println("method2.Calculate() called, input:", m.Input)
}
```

And now the serialization / deserialization process:

```
// Register the values we use for the Method interface
gob.Register(&method1{})
gob.Register(&method2{})

model := Calculator{
    Method: NewMethod1("inputData"),
}
model.Method.Calculcate()

buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
enc := gob.NewEncoder(buf)
if err := enc.Encode(model); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(buf.Bytes())

var model2 Calculator
dec := gob.NewDecoder(buf)
if err := dec.Decode(&model2); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
model2.Method.Calculcate()
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SSgKGGTVwKr)):

```
method1.Calculate() called, input: inputData
[35 255 129 3 1 1 10 67 97 108 99 117 108 97 116 111 114 1 255 130 0 1 1 1 6 77 101 116 104 111 100 1 16 0 0 0 48 255 130 1 13 42 109 97 105 110 46 109 101 116 104 111 100 49 255 131 3 1 1 7 109 101 116 104 111 100 49 1 255 132 0 1 1 1 5 73 110 112 117 116 1 12 0 0 0 16 255 132 12 1 9 105 110 112 117 116 68 97 116 97 0 0]
method1.Calculate() called, input: inputData
```